# How Do I use two APIs at time while one is http and another is https

Tags: javascript, angular

How Do I use two APIs at time while one is http and another is https in Angular or JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to change much, there's no limit on how many different apis you can talk with at once. Just make sure to use the correct urls. You might have to set on option on your http client (axios, fetch, etc.) to allow non-secure http connections when you are communicating with the http api.